# How access server side cookies in a axios intercepor and outside of getServerSideProps()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my nextjs app, I created a separate file for my axios interceptors and I'm making a request in getServerSideProps() which needs to have a Authorization header with some access token. I'm doing the logic for attaching headers inside mu interceptors but I need to access the cookie outside of getServerSideProps() and in my interceptor. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but may be useful for someone. You'll need to create an API route to retrieve the cookie as usually you'll need to pass the `req` and `res` to the cookie lib you're using like `cookies-next`.

So you create a route like `/api/token` and then place a code like this:

```
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const token = getCookie('site-jwt', { req, res });
  res.status(200).json({ token });
}
```

and then in your interceptor, you do a fetch

```
const { token } = await fetch('/api/token').then(r => r.json())
```

Comment: Hi, i am now getting error `````code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL',`````  why is that?